# Homemade DC motor won’t turn

Tags: brushed-dc-motor

I’m trying to build a DC motor powered by a 9V battery. The motor consists of a 3mm diameter steel rod, PVC I cut for the armature, 28 gauge insulated magnetic copper wire, 2 neodymium magnets, and bare copper as the commutators.
I used a singular string of copper wire wound 60 times around each armature and is completely stripped on the parts where it touches each commutator, and as far as I know the wire doesn’t come into contact with the steel rod at all.
The magnets are below the armature under the tape in the picture.
When I attach the 9V battery to 2 of the commutators there’s no spin, but I do see sparks. I don’t know what I am doing wrong as I have seen many videos with similarly build DC motors, any advice?

[image]

[image]   [image]

Update: I’ve gotten rid of the PVC and am using screws instead with 100 turns of 28 gauge copper wire. I also changed from a 9V battery to 4 AA batteries in series and can now see some torque with the motor but not enough for a full revolution, I think now it’s just a matter of playing around with the amount of copper wire used.

Final update: I finally got the motor to run. I changed my armature to tin-coated steel and made 600 total loops of 28 gauge wire. One of my commutator plates isn’t working so I need to fix that but besides that small issue it works with two 9V batteries connected in parallel. Thank you to everyone who helped me with this. [image]
[image]

Comment: Move your magnets as close to the armature as you can get them without touching. When you connect to the commutator, experiment with different angles - perpendicular to the base, parallel to the base various angles in between ...

Comment: Did you follow a specific design plan?  If you include that information you may get better help.  Soldering the wires to the commutators would be one improvement.

Comment: @Nedd yes, I was going for something like this design https://youtu.be/HZE6cg5IN9o

Comment: @brhans I’ve tried that, also tried using more/less magnets still with similar results

Comment: @Nitrsa  The youtube design by-passes a lot of the operational theory. Review this simple 3 pole virtual design with more working knowledge of the armature to permanent magnet interaction.  http://www.dynamicscience.com.au/tester/solutions1/electric/3poledcmotot.html

Comment: Similar youtube of above design with even more info.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1673-0Y3fFQ

Comment: @Nedd In the 3 pole virtual design it says a DC motor is generated by 3 electromagnets. My wire is only touching the PVC armature and the commutator, do I need to have it touching a magnetic metal on the armature?

Comment: what type of a 9 V battery are you using? ... a standard 9V block battery does not provide much current ... it is six AAAA cells in series ... try six AA cells instead

Comment: @jsotola I never thought about using batteries in series. I was just using a 9V block battery, and I had some casings for AA batteries but only up to 6V which I didn’t think would be enough. Thank you

Comment: Did you strip the insulation at your commutator?  Strip it and add some solder.  If you have a DMM, measure resistance from commutator segments.

Comment: @Nitrsa the comment fields are not a place to teach electro-magnetics/motor theory, you've been given a lot of information through the references and comments to begin improving your design, make the modification as you see fit. You might draw out your design on paper and compare it to the references. Then if still not working come back and let us know if there are further problems.  Best of luck in your learning experience.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat the insulation is completely stripped where it makes contact with the commutator but I was waiting for it to work before I added solder in case I needed to increase/decrease wire used. I do have a DMM, I’ll give checking the resistance a shot

Comment: coils wound on **PVC**?? Magnetic paths are almost entirely low-permeability, where they should be through high-permeability iron. A real (toy) motor uses laminated transformer iron instead. You DO have the shape right. In the manufactured (toy) motor, the only low-permeability region is the air-gap between rotating armature, and stationary magnets...a very small disruption that nevertheless limits magnetic flux.

Comment: @glen_geek I saw someone make a similar motor with cardboard and no laminated iron so I was copying that design but with PVC, but now I’m planning to add either iron or steel to the armature, I just need to figure out how to do so without it touching the copper windings. Thank you for the help

Comment: @Nedd I think I have the new design planned out correctly after looking into the virtual design, thank you for the help

Comment: Nitrsa, I'd expect *a bit of torque* from your design - I've seen many crude home-constructed motors rotate, with horrendous magnetic air-paths. Perhaps you can try an intermediate step: start with a pre-wound toy motor armature/brush assembly, and add your "neo-magnets" to replace the two ceramic magnets usually found inside the motor shell. Take note of torque, and make an effort to arrange this external fixed magnetic path (that crosses through the axis of the rotating armature) to maximize torque. That'll help give you a feel for mechanical/electrical efficiency.

Comment: @glen_geek I’ve already done that with a handheld fan from the store, I replaced the permanent magnets and redid the windings with my own magnetic wire and it works no problem. Which is why I’m so stuck on my design, because other than mine being significantly larger and not having the iron armature core, everything else is the same, so I’m assuming my armature just needs a  highly permeable metal core

Comment: The iron core concentrates the flux.

Comment: You may also have to double check your winding directions if the motor only spins partial turns. Apply power and rotate the motor by hand, does it always make torque in the same direction?

Answer (score 2):

The rotor was wound on a plastic armature. That's not going to work - at least not in any practical sense. One may, with a lot of unnecessary effort, get the motor to turn. But practical torques won't be possible. Instead of plastic, cut steel sheets should be used. Those can be cut with scissors (when thin), using a template cut from thick paper to mark them. But that's tedious.

The shape can be drawn in, say, Inkscape, and then laser-cut from steel sheet by one of many online services. Or they can be scrounged from a motor that was disassembled for "components".

The question is also incomplete because it only shows the rotor. The rest matters too!